# android Shared Preferences issue

Tags: android

i want to force use to fill Settings Page in two cases

1) when user first launch Application 
2) when database version is change i want that setting page should be filled first before proceding

in my Setting class i set shared preferences  "false" , and then i check it in below code

class setting //main class
 String flag = sharedPreferences.getString("CreatedFlag","");

```
     if(flag.equals("true"))
       {
            // Move to second activity
            Intent i =new Intent();
            i.setClass(someclass.this,otherPage.class );
             startActivity(i);
            finish();
       }
     else
     { // Stay on Settings page }
```

Problem : it run fine when user first launch application ,it show setting page and fill tht page ,
but when user run application second time it show setting page again ,coz shared preference still have true value ,
thn again user run app 3rd time Shared Preference have update value which is false ,and show other page

what i want is tht Setting page show only once if its there is no setting define ,other wise it goes to home page

need help ,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont shee here where you're actually saving the preferences, I assume its in the otherPage activity??

If not add this to the first activity

```
SharedPreferences prefs = this.getsharedPreferences("myApp",0);
//check for the Created value in the shared preferences
String createdFlag = prefs.getString("Created","false"); // set default value == false
if(createdFlag == "false){
    goToSettingsPage(); // to the settings page we go...
}
```

Then on your settings page:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = this.getSharedPreferences("myApp",0);
SharedPreferences.Editor ed = prefs.edit(); // create the editor
ed.putString("Created","true"); // put the value to the prefs
ed.commit(); // commit the changes
```

After the first run, the shared prefs file will be persisted, and then should not goto the settings page the second time its run.